# Не могу вызвать метод в Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation, selenide

Имею тест:

```
@Test
public void yandexMarket(){
    open("https://yandex.ru/", YandexMainPage.class)
    .search("яндекс маркет")
    .goLink(YandexSearchResult.class)
    .categoryGo(BeforePhonesCategory.class);
}
```

Где не могу вызвать метод categoryGo, остальные методы вызываются без проблем, но Selenide почему-то не видит именно .categoryGo.

Сам метод:

```
public class Tests extends BaseTest {

public class BeforePhonesCategory  extends BaseTest  {

    @Step("Переходим в категорию телефоны {goCategory}")
    public void categoryGo(){

        SelenideElement goCat = $x("//a[@href='/catalog--elektronika/54440']");
        goCat.click();
        switchTo().window(1);

        SelenideElement goCat2 = $x("//a[@href='/catalog--mobilnye-telefony/54726/list?hid=91491']");
        goCat2.click();
        switchTo().window(1);

    }
}
```

Метод goLink

```
public class YandexSearchResult  extends BaseTest  {

    @Step("Переходим по имени ссылки {linkName}")
    public <T extends BaseTest > T goLink (Class<T> typeNextPage){
        SelenideElement goSite = $x("//div[contains(@class, 'organic ') and contains(@class, 'bno')]");
        goSite.$x(".//a[@href]").click();
        switchTo().window(1);
        return typeNextPage.cast(page(typeNextPage));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, в качестве параметра метода Вам надо передавать класс, содержащий следующий метод. Т.е. вмиесто `.goLink(YandexSearchResult.class)` надо использовать `.goLink(BeforePhonesCategory.class)`.

В таком случае, после точки, Вы должны увидеть метод `categoryGo(..)`, из класса `BeforePhonesCategory`.

Comment: Случайно оставил ";", но все равно не могу вызвать categoryGo

Comment: Покажите метод `goLink`

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: @OttoRahn Обновил ответ